# How to trigger the nature day event?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

My island is a Northern Hemisphere island.

Nature day is a event beginning on 23rd Apr, and ending on 4th May.

My game version is currently 1.10.0

I've set my system date to 22nd April, saved the game, quit, and set the date to 23rd April and started the game. There is no announcement of nature day in the mail or by Isabelle. How do I trigger the nature day event by time-travelling?

In general, how can I trigger past time-based events?